# Spring Boot 2.1.5: Failed to replace {0} with Field Name on Validation Message

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to upgrade spring-boot 2.1.4 to 2.1.5.

In spring-boot 2.1.4, custom validation error message with {0} arguments correctly replace with Field Name.
But spring-boot 2.1.5, validation error message shows {0} as it is.

#### code

- messages.properties

```
notblank={0} must not be blank
```

- PersonForm

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

class PersonForm {

    @NotBlank(message = "{notblank}")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person(Name: " + this.name + ")";
    }
}
```

Here's my sample project.
https://github.com/spikefin-goby/spring-boot-validation-sample

#### spring-boot 2.1.4 result

In spring-boot 2.1.4, display 「name must not be blank」
(correctly replace {0} with Field Name )
[spring-boot 2.1.4 validation message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIorC.png)

BingingResult.errors[0] is `FieldError` class

---

#### spring-boot 2.1.5 result

But spring-boot 2.1.5, display 「**{0} must not be blank**」
[spring-boot 2.1.5 validation message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIPGK.png)

BingingResult.errors[0] is `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` class

---

What can I do about this?

---

### Update

Spring Boot 2.1.6 has been released in June 19, 2019.
This problem is fixed!

In spring-boot 2.1.6, display 「name must not be blank」
(correctly replace {0} with Field Name )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my eyes, you run into the [issue #23014: validation error message {0} is not working](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23014) in spring-context-5.1.7

Comment: Thank you for the information.@Lesiak  I will wait for spring-context-5.1.8.
At the same time I'll think about to fix this code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an Exception Handler like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
        String error = String.format("%s.%s: %s", violation.getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName(),
                violation.getPropertyPath(), violation.getMessage());
        errors.add(error);
        logger.error(error);
    }

    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errors);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
}
```

`violation.getPropertyPath()` returns the name of the field that threw the violation.

As a side note: I'm using my self made class `ApiError` to display errors. You don't need to do it that way but it's important that you iterate the constraint violations inside your `ConstraintViolationException` to get the property path of each of them.